# How to create the scratches pattern from a mason jar lid

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm trying to create these scratches that are going across the surface of the lid like the picture below. [image]

So far this is what I have going with my material nodes and the result of it.

Nodes Setup:
[image]

Result:

[image]

My setup doesn't seem to be correct and I'm stuck. Please let me know if I'm heading in the right direction. If not, please correct and let me know what I should do. Thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scratches in your reference image are more rare than in your material, you need to push both the needles to the right or left, and also make the color slightly darker to make the material a bit glossier:

[image]